# Java EE (JBoss) monitoring

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, monitoring

What is the best way to monitor a Java EE (JBoss) application?
It should be free to use (and open source would be great).

I did a bit of research and i found ways to monitor JBoss apps but mostly it is about monitoring the running threads, CPU, memory and stuff like that which is non of my requirements (e.g. http://rhq-project.github.io/rhq/).

What should be monitored are actions initiated by a user (what methods were called, how many times, how long did these requests take, how many database calls were done, which objects were affected...). The source of the request can be arbitary (JSF, a webservice, a queue...). Can this probably be done with https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Redhat has a product called JBoss Operations Network (JON) and is very comprehensive: http://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/operations-network

Also you can use the JBoss command line interface (jboss-cli) which you can get a lot of information from -- there is also a jconsole script bundled in JBoss install which includes a CLI tab along with all the other jconsole tabs.

Comment: Ty - I had a look at it and it seems like this goes way too far for the given requirements. Also it is a commercial product (I edited the question - it should be free to use - sry that I missed this).

Comment: JON is actually the RHQ+support

Answer (score 0):

RHQ is able to monitor also the time of the method calls (so called call-time metrics), data sources, etc. If you can modify the code of the monitored app, I recommend going through this blog post http://pilhuhn.blogspot.cz/2013/01/monitoring-monster.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CLI. Anything you see in the Admin Console is available through the CLI. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes for some examples.